# Execute JS code after setTimeout() callback completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
function newGraphic() {
  $.post('./lexiconGraph.pl', {
    'tag' : this.getAttribute('apolo'),
    'apoloKey' : this.id,
    'h' : surface.h,
    'w' : surface.w,
    'operation' : 'newGraphic'
  }, function(result) {
    minGraphic();
    // STOP AND WAIT //
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = result;
    getNodes();
    // STOP AND WAIT //
    maxGraphic();
  });
}

function minGraphic() {
  if (z > 0.01) {
    zoom(parseFloat(z - 0.01));
    setTimeout('minGraphic();', 5);
  }
}
```

The problem is: The function *minGraphic* creates an "animation effect" of unknown duration (*depends on the size of the graph*). I need to find a way to make the following lines are executed **only when the function *minGraphic* finished**.
Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

---

**NOTE:** Put the following lines in the function *minGraphic* is **not** an option, since I already use this function elsewhere.

Comment: If you cannot edit the function minGraphic, then providing a solution also appears to be **not** an option.

Comment: @Adam This is not true. See my answer.

Comment: @DerFlatulator - what answer?

Comment: @Adam, It was removed after I indicated that it wouldn't be working.

Comment: That's what I get for answering questions way after my bedtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback for when the animation is complete.  Something like this:

```
function newGraphic() {
  $.post('./lexiconGraph.pl', {
    'tag' : this.getAttribute('apolo'),
    'apoloKey' : this.id,
    'h' : surface.h,
    'w' : surface.w,
    'operation' : 'newGraphic'
  }, function(result) {
    var afterAnimation = function()
    {
      document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = result;
      getNodes();
      maxGraphic();
    };

    minGraphic(afterAnimation);
  });
}

function minGraphic(cb) {
  if (z > 0.01) {
    zoom(parseFloat(z - 0.01));
    setTimeout(function() { minGraphic(cb); }, 5);
  }
  else
  {
    if(cb) cb();
  }
}
```

If I'm following correctly, what this will do is trigger the start of miniGraphic, passing in a callback to a function that will execute after the animation is complete (i.e. z is not > 0.01).  When that event happens, if a callback (`cb`) was passed in, it will call that function, thus triggering the next step in the animation.

If you have stuff you need to *wait* on for the `maxGraphic` method, then you can adopt the same concept.

Alternatively, if jQuery is available to you, jQuery has built-in ways for post-animation callbacks that you can use.  [See this documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a callback?

```
function minGraphic(callback) {
  if (z > 0.01) {
    zoom(parseFloat(z - 0.01));
    setTimeout($.proxy(minGraphic, this, callback), 5);
    return;
  }
  callback && callback();
}
```

Then just call the function like:

```
minGraphic(function () {
    //complete
});
```

Note that the `callback` argument is optionnal to stay backward compatible with previous code not interested in knowing when the operation was completed.